# How to filter Sequelize query by enum values

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to do something like below:

```
  # job_type: is of type Array of Enum

  const profiles = await Profile.findAll({
    where: {
      job_type: { [Op.in]: ['Contract', 'Permanent'] },
    },
  });
```

The above produces an error below

```
values.map is not a function
```

The above error kinda makes sense seeing as `job_type` is an array of enum.

```
job_type: DataTypes.ARRAY(
   DataTypes.ENUM({
     values: ['Contract', 'Temp', 'Volunteer', 'Permanent'],
   })
),
```

Stack trace

```
Trace: TypeError: values.map is not a function
    at ARRAY._value (/Users/########/Desktop/####-backend/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/data-types.js:379:19)
    at ARRAY._stringify (/Users/########/Desktop/####-backend/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/data-types.js:393:29)
    at ARRAY.stringify (/Users/########/Desktop/####-backend/node_modules/sequelize/lib/data-types.js:22:19)
    at PostgresQueryGenerator.escape (/Users/########/Desktop/####-backend/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:702:30)
    at /Users/########/Desktop/####-backend/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:1908:71
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at PostgresQueryGenerator._whereParseSingleValueObject (/Users/########/Desktop/####-backend/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:1908:52)
    at PostgresQueryGenerator.whereItemQuery (/Users/########/Desktop/####-backend/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:1728:21)
    at /Users/########/Desktop/####-backend/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:1649:25
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

If anyone comes across a process to filter by enum values, I will appreciate any input.

Comment: Did you try `Op.any`?

Comment: got me closer but with this error: "operator does not exist: \"enum_Profiles_job_type\"[] = \"enum_Profiles_job_type\""

Comment: Do you have stacktrace for `values.map is not a function`?

Comment: @Anatoly I have added stacktrace for `value.map is not a function` error, feels like a type cast issue, I will dig a little more into it.

Answer (score 0):

Got a solution to the problem, looking closely at how postgres manages enum and running raw SQL I was able to get the desired result with:

```
const result = await sequelize.query(
  `SELECT * FROM "Profiles" WHERE array['Contract','Permanent']::"enum_Profiles_job_type"[] @> "job_type"`
);
```

Without using raw query I was able to solve it with:

```
const profiles = await Profile.findAll({
  where: {
    job_type: { [Op.contains]: ['Temp','Permanent'] }
  },
});
return profiles;
```

`Op.contains` referenced from [sequelize-postgres-only-range-operators](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-basics/#postgres-only-range-operators)